# Date Picker does not work in another routing page or when come back in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a vue js app.There is two routing page A and B. Both are contains setting option with 3 set of date picker. 
If I am in page A that time datepickers of page A is working but when I go to page B it does not work. Even If I get back again to page A , it does not work.
Only work after refresh the page.

[image]

```js
$(function () {

/// col 1 DateTimePicker
        $('#col1vis').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
        $('#col1bis').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#col1vis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#col1bis').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#col1bis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#col1vis').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
        /// col 2 DateTimePicker

        /// col 2 DateTimePicker
              $('#col2vis').datetimepicker({
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
              });
              $('#col2bis').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                  useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
              });
              $("#col2vis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                  $('#col2bis').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
              });
              $("#col2bis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                  $('#col2vis').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
              });

        /// col 2 DateTimePicker
              $('#col3vis').datetimepicker({
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
              });
              $('#col3bis').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                  useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
              });
              $("#col3vis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                  $('#col3bis').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
              });
              $("#col3bis").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                  $('#col3vis').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
              });
    });
```

Comment: Where is this script located? Is it loaded with each page change? is it cached? is it loaded once? (I assume it's loaded only once)

Answer (score 0):

You must never make a change to an element Vuejs manages because Vue won’t be aware of the change and is going to go right ahead and overwrite it in the next update cycle.

So you can try to wrapper your datepicker to a new component, or better, try to think in Vue and just put jQuery away.

You can read how to safely use jQuery with Vuejs in this link: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/